# How to access the data inside of Gathering Future finished result

Tags: python-3.x, future, python-asyncio, aiohttp, concurrent.futures

Been trying to figure out how I can access my data after I return it. This is a sample of x if I print it:

```
<_GatheringFuture finished result=[[{'ip': '173.245.203.70'}], [{'ip': '196.52.2.82'}], [{'ip': '69.161.4.1'}], [{'ip':'73.180.140.205'}], [{'ip': '96.242.181.128'}], [{'ip': '108.208.74.183'}], ...]>
```

I tried x[0], x.result, x.results, etc... but just kept getting errors. Anyone know how to access the data in the Future result? Thank you for your time! Here is the full code below:

```
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiohttp import ClientSession

HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
proxy = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx'

async def fetch(url, session):
 while True:
  x = []
  try:
   async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, proxy="http://{}".format(proxy), timeout=9) as r:
    print (r.status)
    if r.status == 200:
     data = await r.read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
     for ip in soup.select('tr +  tr td font'):
      array.append({'ip' : ip.get_text()})
     break
  except:
   pass
 return x

async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
 async with sem:
  return await fetch(url, session)

async def run(num):
 tasks = []
 sem = asyncio.Semaphore(300)

 async with ClientSession() as session:
  for i in range(0,num):
   task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, 'http://ip4.me', session))
   tasks.append(task)

  responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  await responses
  return responses

if __name__ == '__main__':
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(10))
 x = loop.run_until_complete(future)
 loop.close()
 print (x)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here `responses` you return is a future you got from `asyncio.gather`:

```
responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
await responses
return responses
```

What you want is result of this future. Change you code like this:

```
responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
return responses
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for the explanation, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Either simply `return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`